# Why does the size of my UIView (loaded from a UIViewController) is nul, CGSizeZero, zero,...?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

## The situation

I add a view (loaded by a view controller) to another view. After having added it, the view has a `size` equal to `(0,0)`. I don't understand why and I would like to know.

I know how to solve this problem (with constraints, either created automatically with `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES` either created "by hand").

> What I really want is understanding why, in this case, it does not
>   work.

## Code

Code of my main View Controller

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) ColorViewController * colorVC ;
@end

@implementation ViewController

+ (void)fillView:(UIView *)bigView
        withView:(UIView *)view
{
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO ;
    //     view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES ;

    view.frame = bigView.bounds ;

    [bigView addSubview:view] ;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.colorVC = [ColorViewController new] ;

    [ViewController fillView:self.mainView
                    withView:self.colorVC.view] ;
}


@end
```

The associated storyboard
[image]
Capture d’écran 2015-04-30 à 17.25.32.png

Code of `ColorViewController`

```
@implementation ColorViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0
    CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from white
    CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from black
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];

    self.view.backgroundColor = color ;
}


@end
```

Its XIB

[image]

## Log

If I log the view (of `ColorViewController`), I get:

```
2015-04-30 17:33:58.329 TEST_SUBVIEWS[51745:602214] <UIView: 0x7b4191e0; frame = (-179 -236; 0 0); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b418ce0>>
```

## The strangest things

- What is really strange in this is that if I remove the only object in the above XIB (the `UILabel`), then, everything works well.
- Also, if I create the view with `[UIView new]` and then use the same method to add it to the "main view", then everything works well.

Strange?

## Link to a minimal non-working example on github

https://github.com/colasjojo/ToyProjectForIssueWithSize

Comment: I don't understand your code. Why are you making `newView` and then throwing it away? And what is `self.mainView`? Is it the same as `self.view`?

Comment: Sorry, `newView` is useless, I will remove it. `self.mainView` is an `IBoutlet` from the storyboard. `self.view` is totally unrelated. It belongs to `ColorViewController`.

Comment: Yup, got it (by looking at the github project, good idea putting that up)

Comment: When you embed a view controller's view in another view controller, you need to tell both view controllers - so that appropriate layout/touch related messages are forwarded to the child.  See "Implementing a Custom Container View Controller" in [this Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Comment: But I am not implementing a Custom Container View Controller !!!!

Comment: You are putting one VC's view as a subview of another VC, so I think you will need to use the `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController` type handoff described in that document.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973948/shall-i-really-use-addchildviewcontroller-when-i-add-a-view-to-another-view

Answer (score 5):

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO ;
```

That means: "Use auto layout to set my size and position." But you have no auto layout constraints, so you get nonsense when layout occurs. Thus the inserted view never appears.

You also ask about the presence / absence of the label and how it affects this result. It isn't just a label. It's *any* subview. It's because the presence of subviews affects how auto layout operates. With no subviews, auto layout seems to say, "okay, nothing to do here". Thus, you do see the inserted view in the right place, but that's sort of an accident (just dumb luck, if you see what I mean).

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

That means: use my frame to *make* constraints. Thus, when layout happens, we *do* have constraints and the inserted view view appears where you expect.

In your case, you are best off saying *nothing* in your code about `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, because you have not applied any explicit constraints to your views, so you are given implicit constraints derived from the frame, which is what you want. Alternatively, you could turn off auto layout entirely - it is turned on in both your nibs.

Comment: OK, but how do you explain that if your remove the `UILabel` from the `XIB` of `ColorViewController`, then it works?

Comment: By the way, do you know some good documents explaining stuff about `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`? Thanks!

Comment: Added more about the label to my answer.

Comment: I do know a good explanation of auto layout but modesty prevents me from mentioning it. :)

Comment: Meaning you are an Apple developer and created this system?

Comment: No, I've never worked for Apple (or anyone), and I think Ken Ferry created auto layout. He is smarter than I am! Trust me on that one.

Comment: So, what does your modesty prevent you to tell me?

Comment: Another remark: if I add an empty view, in the same way, but the view is created by `[UIView new]` and not *via* a controller, I don't have the problem...